# Can a single table be a child to two parent tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a question table, and an answer table.

I then have a comments table, so that comments can be attached to a question or an answer. There an be many comments for each question or answer.

Should I create two comments tables?  Or relate both question and answer table to a single comments table.  I would prefer this, but it seems like it would be non-normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.  In general, you would like to have foreign key relationships.  If there is only one comment allowed per question/answer, then it is easy.  A `commentId` goes in each of the tables, `Questions` and `Answers`.  There is an easy foreign key relationship.

To maintain the foreign key relationships and allow multiple comments is a bit tricker.  Probably the easiest way is to have two junction tables, `QuestionComments` and `AnswerComments`.  This would like to the appropriate parent and to the `Comments` table.

Note:  there are reasons why you would want separate comments tables for the two purposes.  For instance, you might classify the comments on answers into different groups.  Or, you might only allow one comment per user on a question.  These different business rules might be easier to implement if the comments are in different tables.

Comment: To expand on Gordon’s Answer…   It is possible that your question is revealing a missing table in your schema or something you are just about to realize.   If a Child table does not obviously have a single parent key on a single table you may be about to do something you will regret later.   My default answer without knowing anything about your situation is that you want two tables.    This detail would probably manifest itself when you join the FK to the “Test Taking Instance Id” table in your model.

Comment: @SqlSurfer You speak sooth.

Answer (score 3):

Create comments table with two foreign keys from question and answer tables. Its enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can use comment table to answer,question table via using join

```
       table question: 
id |questionDes |commentId|
1  |  what      | 2        |

table answer
|id | answerDes| commentId|
|201| yes      |      44  |
table comment
|id |commentDes| commentId|
|2  | hi       |2         |
|4  |nii       | 44       |

you sql query will be--
SELECT questionDes.question, commemtDes.comment
FROM question
INNER JOIN comment
ON commentId.question=commentId.comment;
and
SELECT answerDes.answer, commemtDes.comment
FROM answer
INNER JOIN comment
ON commentId.answer=commentId.comment;
```